# Is there a way to filter out hidden elements with css?

Tags: css, selenium

as an example some html has several elements which have the css path `table.class1.class2[role="menu"]` but only one of these elements will be visible at any given time, so I want to get only the one that is visible.
can I adjust my css path to narrow it down?

Comment: But, you can filter the list using `Selenium` api

Comment: depends how they're hidden

Comment: @Saifur how can I use Selenium?

Comment: @DavidThomas The elements do not look the same. They are menus, each having different menu options

Comment: Then add that information to your question, and state *why* you need to select only a specific element! and show how you're triggering the showing/hiding.

Comment: @CupawnTae what are some different ways they can be hidden? I thought `display='none'` is the only way. If a parent element has this attribute could I filter it this way?

Comment: @DavidThomas I am not sure how the elements are hidden, possibly through a parent element.

Comment: Well, there are lots of styling combination that can make things invisible and/or take them out of the page flow. But I was referring more to whether they're being hidden e.g. by adding a `style="display:none"`, which you could then include in the css path as an attribute-based selector. And for example, jQuery hides things this way

Comment: @DavidThomas I did not create the website I am only trying to use selenium to navigate it

Comment: use web inspector to find out?

Comment: easier said than done, Ive spent quite some time looking at the html that is available I have not found anything yet, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly use `Linq` to get the list. I am not sure which language you are using. But, similar concept can be applied using any of them. Using `Linq`
to accomplish this kind of scenario is very simple in `C#`

```
public IWebElement Test()
{
    //selector
    By bycss = By.CssSelector("table.class1.class2[role='menu']");

    return Driver.FindElements(bycss).ToList().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Displayed);
}
```

And, make sure to import 
`using System.Linq;` if you are using `C#`

**In Java you can do something like this[not using lambdas]**

```
List<WebElement> visibleList = null;
//selector
By byCss = By.cssSelector("table.class1.class2[role='menu']");
//list of visible and hidden elements
Iterator<WebElement> iterator = driver.findElements(byCss).iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()){
    WebElement element = iterator.next();
 if (element.isDisplayed()){
     //building the list of visible elements
     visibleList.add(element);
 }
}

//get the first item of the list
//you can return all if needed
return visibleList.get(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

In Java, you can use [`WebElement.isDisplayed()`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed%28%29).